# Disable specific step in jQuery slider widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am using [jQuery-ui slider](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) and I am initializing the slider giving:

min value: 0

max value: 5

and enabling step option.

On page load, the slider handler in the first step (0).
Up to here all are ok.

**Issue:** When user slides the handler to any of the other steps (1 to 5), he must **not** be able to reselect step 0.

**IN SHORT: I want to disable step 0 when user moves the handler to another position**

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="eval-card-slider-wrapper noselect col-xs-12 col-lg-5">     
   <div class="col-xs-9">                          
      <div class="eval-card-slider"></div>
   </div>                    
</div>
```

Here is how I initialize the plugin:

```
    $("div.eval-card-slider").slider({
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        step: 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            var that = $(this);
            var val = ui.value;
            that.closest('.eval-card-slider-wrapper').find('.eval-slider-value-holder').attr('data-sliderVal', val);
            qstAverageUpdate(that);
        }
    });
```

**NOTE:** I can not reduce the total steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example make it so that when the user tries to select *0* it goes back to *1* or previous select

```
$("div.eval-card-slider").slider({
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    step: 1,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        if(!$(this).slider("value"))
            $(this).slider("option", "value", 1);
    },
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0660081o/